# How to handle a TCP connection in background? for Poker app server-client app

Tags: ios, tcpclient, poker

I am working on Poker app based on server-client based app. When Poker App goes to the background  after some time TCP/IP connection lost because app unable to send/recieve any packet to/from the server. Sever ends socket connection. how can i able to establish connection for long time and update my game UI

Comment: You can't really.  VoIP apps can use background mode sockets, but you can't use that mode for a game.  You can either use push notifications or just stand up the player from the table

Answer (score 2):

The topic you asked for, is called ["Background Execution"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

*First:*

You can't update the UI while the app enters the background. But you will be able to finish your API-Requests to the server and save the data on phone while using **beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler**. You can use this method to write a block which communicates to your server and handles all the data your app will receive. If the App enters the foreground again, you can use this data received in background to update your UI then.

It is important, that those background tasks have to finish in a short time, so it will be not a good idea here to have an infinite loop. Otherwise, iOS will terminate your process. How much time you really get after your app gets backgrounded is determined by iOS.

*Second:*

If you want to keep tcp/ip-connections always on even if the app remains in the background, Apple provides a very powerful background mode which enables you to run code for any time in the background. It's called VoIP-Services. Unfortunately your app should provide some VoIP-Stuff to not being rejected by Apple. Here is a [good article](https://techmegabyte.wordpress.com/2014/12/10/ios-background-mode-voip-exploring-with-experiments/) about those services.